# C++ File Output for object arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object

Does anyone know how to fout an array like the below to a .dat file?
Let me know if this is not enough information.

My console output shows 4 rows of integers with 6 columns and I want to print that to my file. I can print everything else, but can not figure this one out..

```
for(i=0; i < 4; i++)
{ 
    cout << "  " << i+1; 
    P[i].TeamOutput();
}     

void TeamOutput()           
{
    cout << teamwork << speed << power << defence << injury << endl;    
}
```

Comment: What format are you using for the output file:  binary (mirror image from memory), xml, ini, CSV, etc?  In some cases you'll want human readable and easily editable formats; other cases you may want something that can be efficiently read (and heavily platform specific).

Comment: BTW, there is no standard format for a ".dat" file.  The ".dat" extension implies that the file contains data; usually in a program specific format.  Need more details.

Comment: Where in the *posted code*, are 6 columns printed?  All I see is that a method, `TeamOutput` is called 4 times.

Comment: You may want to consider passing an output stream (by reference) to your class' output method.  This will allow you more alternatives, such as file streams and string streams.

Comment: Windows Notepad is an editor.  You can write FORTRAN, COBOL. LISP, BASIC, C, C++, C#, Pascal, Algol, Ada, Haskell, Smalltalk, etc., using NotePad.  You need to figure out which programming language you are using.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Will edit my post with the code for output

Comment: @ThomasMatthews .... it says in my post title what language I am using

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it. You need a *specific* type of `ostream` to output. `cout` is an `ostream`, but a special one that outputs to the system's console. You need an `ostream` that outputs to a file. This kind of `ostream` is called an `ofstream` and is in the header file `<fstream>`. Here's how you can use it with an array.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std; // It's generally bad to do this

int main()
{
    // Size of array
    const int SIZE = 10;

    // Make the array
    int some_array[10];

    // Fill the array with values
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        some_array[i] = i + 1;
    }

    // THIS is where the magic happens; make the file stream to output to
    ofstream file("file.dat"); // "file.dat" can be replaced by whatever filename

    // Make sure the file opened okay. Otherwise, there's an error
    if (file.is_open())
    { // The file opened just file, so do whatever you need to

        // Save all the info from the array to "file.dat"
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            file << some_array[i] << endl;
        }

        // Make sure to close the 'ofstream' when you're done
        file.close();
    }
    else
    { // The file did NOT open okay; there's an error
        cout << "Error opening file.dat!" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is to output a regular array. I need to output an array that is filled in a member function. My initial response was to try the below but it doesn't work:

    file << P[i].TeamOutput() << endl;